# How select all objects within a JSON string with a specific property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a string called 'products', with each object having multiple fields, like so:

```
var prods = JSON.stringify ({"products": [

    {
        'prodname': 'Linkedin',
        'oem': 'Linkedin',
        'snippet': 'snippet goes here',
        'linkto': 'http://www.linkedin.com',
        'imagesource': 'resources/images/apps/linkedin.png',
        'category' : 'one'
    },
    {
        'prodname': 'Mozy',
        'oem': 'Mozy',
        'snippet': 'Mozy is the world’s most trusted online backup service for consumers and businesses.',
        'linkto': 'This is the app page links.',
        'imagesource': 'resources/images/apps/mozy.png',
        'category' : 'two'
    },
    {
        'prodname': 'Amazon',
        'oem': 'Amazon',
        'snippet': 'snippet goes here',
        'linkto': 'This is the app page links.',
        'imagesource': 'resources/images/apps/amazon.png',
        'category' : 'one'
    },
```

...and continues in this manner.

I've written a script that will create html elements on the page and populate them with data from the string, creating an app-store type look - which works fine. The problem I have is that I want to only display apps from a certain category at one time, so for instance I want to be able to select all the objects in the string which have a 'category' of 'one'.

As it stands, the part of my code that is selecting the elements looks like this:

```
var prodobjects = JSON.parse(prods);

function popcatone(){

  var catnum =  prodobjects.products.category;
  var numberprods = catnum='one'.length;

  var looptimes = 0;
  if (numberprods > 5 & numberprods != 0) {
    looptimes = 5;
  }
  else {
    looptimes = numberprods;
  }
  for (i=0; i < looptimes; i++)

  {  //start loop

var imgsrc =  prodobjects.products[i].imagesource;
var h3text = prodobjects.products[i].prodname;
var oemtext = prodobjects.products[i].oem;
var descriptiontext = prodobjects.products[i].snippet;
var productlink = prodobjects.products[i].linkto;
```

...and then it goes on to distributing the data within html elements. As you can see, the code can currently ascertain how many objects within the string have a 'category' of 'one', and use that to limit the amount of times the code loops if there are less than 5 results, but I simply can't figure out how to actually select the objects with a 'category' of 'one'. As it stands, the code sees the number of results correctly, and indeed renders the correct number of apps onto the page, but the results are simply in a linear order and do not take the category in to account.

I've had a crack at making a fiddle for it but as the css that feeds into it is quite complicated i couldn't get it to represent the behaviour properly. Apologies for the long winded question, and and answers or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

I'm really not looking for someone to do my work for me, if someone can point me in the right direction on how to select the object based on the value of one of the fields, I'm happy to figure the rest out myself!

Thanks for your patience, and just for the record I'm using jquery 1.10.2

Comment: one part of your code confuses me... `'one'.length` Why not just type `3`? likely a logic mistake here.

Comment: @KevinB It's a new level of protection against reverse engineering ;)

Comment: Incidentally, you're not using jQuery anywhere in what you posted.  :-)

Comment: @KevinB ok I see my mistake there now, incidentally there was only 3 apps in the full string with a category of one, hence my confusion lol.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Yeah but I didn't know if a. the answer would require it and also b. Im pretty new to the site so just thought the more info I could give the better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need this to work in older browers*, I would use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function getData(array, type, val) {
  return array.filter(function (el) {
    return el[type] === val;
  });
}

var data = getData(products, 'category', 'one');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/ZH296/)

*[polyfills are available](https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/es5.js).

Comment: I was about to submit a similar answer, but Andy beat me to it and gave a more robust function.

Comment: Absolutely nailed it. Thanks so much Andy!

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var numberprods = catnum='one'.length;
```

sets both "catnum" and "numberprods" to 3.

The line before it:

```
var catnum =  prodobjects.products.category;
```

will always set "catnum" to `undefined`, because the property "products" has an array for its value, and the array doesn't have a "category" property.  That's not super important however because of that next line.

Thus "looptimes" will *always* be 3.

The code, in summary, *cannot* "ascertain how many objects within the string have a 'category' of 'one'".

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, was useful in troubleshooting :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function popcatone(){
    var looptimes = prodobjects.length;
    for (i=0; i < looptimes; i++){
        if(prodobjects.products[i].category == "one"){
            var imgsrc =  prodobjects.products[i].imagesource;
            var h3text = prodobjects.products[i].prodname;
            var oemtext = prodobjects.products[i].oem;
            var descriptiontext = prodobjects.products[i].snippet;
            var productlink = prodobjects.products[i].linkto;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get this to work, but I really appreciate your answer anyhow and it's probably my incompetence, not the codes fault!!